# Synchronous pipe() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I might have some readable stream `instream` and want to, say, write it to a file, so I do

```
instream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.txt'));
```

However, this is an asynchronous operation and returns immediately. I understand that I can attach a handler to the `'finish'` event of the output stream. But often, especially in simple scripts, I'd rather wait around until the `pipe()` has finished.

Is there a way to make the above operation synchronous?

Comment: As far as I know, streams are only asynchronous in node.js.  You could implement a synchronous file copy, but not with streams.

Comment: @laggingreflex: `readFileSync`? I'm trying to write to `out.txt`.

Comment: @jfriend00, streams in node are not only async else stdout and stderr would not output correctly. The docs even state those streams are synchronous so it is possible to make synchronous streams

Comment: @gman - Not sure what you mean by stdout and stedrr have to be synchronous.  Makes no sense to me.  Streams are entirely event driven.  All output from them comes via events.  Even when reading stdout, you get your data via event handlers except in a few cases with synchronous child_process functions which is an entirely different thing from what you're looking at here.

Comment: [From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout), "Writes may be synchronous depending on what the stream is connected" so it's clearly possible to have a synchronous stream.